# What kind of math and science resources/background did Norbert Kricke use for his sculpture?

Tags: art, book, reference, post-war, albert-einstein

It is well known that Norbert Kricke used the book "Plastik des XX. Jahrhundert" by Carola Giedion-Welcker as a reference and saw his artistic ideas reflected by the text ([cf. PhD thesis by Michaela Kamburowa in the introduction](https://hss-opus.ub.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/opus4/frontdoor/index/index/year/2018/docId/2877)). On the other hand, it is often said, for example in the text just cited, that Kricke got inspired for his sculptures (dubbed by himself as "Raumkurven" or "Raumplastik") by scientific ideas of the 20. century, like the fourth dimension of Albert Einstein's space-time. He wanted to find an artistic expression of this new notion of space which replaces an old notion of space ("Leiche Raum") and provides the viewer with a certain sense of freedom.

My question concerning this well-known state of the art interpretation of Kricke's sculpture is: What scientific background about physics and math, especially, did he obtain for his artistic interpretation? What kind of math and science books did he read? How did his ideas in this direction take form and be guided by what resources (whatever reference is allowed: popular science, science communication, science fiction, scientific articles, etc.)?

Comment: Does one need a deep mathematical or scientific background to understand his sculptures (say, [Algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry)? If not, maybe there is also no deep mathematical or scientific background necessary to *create* such sculptures?

Comment: E.g. stuff like space time can be understood to a fairly useful degree from popular science articles in newspapers etc.

Comment: @Jan - This kind of reminds me of Rick Beato analyzing Seal's Kiss of a Rose. He made a [30 minute video analyzing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hhgoli8klLA) every instrument, chord, and note choice with the aid of computer sound software and talking about why they were genius. Then a few months later he interviewed Seal about it, and the dude just said he did the notes that felt right.

Comment: @Jan Even if, I would like to know which newspaper articles inspired him in particular. So that I can read them as well, and make a connection between science and art. 

Comment: @Jan For an artist, even rather trivial material, eg. an interview in the TV with a physicist, can be of special importance, and key to the understanding of his work. I would like to find out if there's a deeper connection to science than just the fourth dimension of Einstein's space time, which is a bit vague.